# Installation of PHP to ASP.NET migration tool on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, vb.net, code-conversion

I am attempting to install the [PHP to ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet) migration tool on W7 64 that has .NET 4, MVC2/3, VS 2010 installed. I had to load asp.net 1.1 to at least get the installed to run. However install fails. I am wondering if anyone has successfully installed the migration tool on modern day asp.net environments? The error message is "The installer was interrupted before the assistant could be installed. And in the application error box "The instruction at 0x0050fce8...Memory could not be written.

Anyone have any ideas. I 'd like to get it installed so i can convert some PHP code to c# and then VB.NET. It would be a big help if a tool can at least do some of it.

And i do know about phalanger which i am not interested in using at least not until i have tried conversion.

---

I am unable to install it on w7 64. I installed vs 2003 and then tried again to install the migration tool with no success. Likely will try i in a virtual xp environment at some point - i have 1500 lines of php to work on.

Comment: updated to include link to the php asp.net migration tool

Comment: It would probably be faster, cleaner and all around better if you just manually rewrite the 1500 lines of code in your final, desired language.  Partly due to the fact that this migration tool, if you get it work, only migrates to .NET 1.x.  It would be nice to bring the code up to some of the later technologies that .NET 3.5+ offers.  Generics, collection initializes, optional parameters, etc. Of course, this is all my opinion and doesn't actually help you get an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post; though now I'm going to agree with @Matt: re-writing 1500 lines is probably easier than converting through _two_ different languages.

Comment: Thanks Matt and sarnold for the advice. I had not even considered the fact that the code would 1.1 if i even got the tool working.